# Automating adobe pdf export

Tags: pdf, applescript, adobe, adobe-indesign

i'm trying to use Apple script for automating the process of exporting PDF's in Adobe indesign,
I can get to the export menu no problem usign "Command e" command but not futher.

I have also tried using system events witch seems like a simpler route, by selecting the preset through:
File > Adobe PDF Presets > "My Preset 1...",

All i get is "Can't make (File > Adobe PDF Presets > "My Preset 1...") into type integer.

So what i need help with is navigating through system events so i can select the preset i want to use.

From my understanding it should look something like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe InDesign 2020"
        set frontmost to true
        delay 1
        click menu item "My Preset 1..." of menu of menu item "Adobe PDF Presets" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Consider using inDesign's AppleScript API for this and not System Events. This [example](https://paste.ee/p/X6XvL) should provide you with a better understanding of what you need to do. Currently this example gist assumes; you have a InDesign document open, and the PDF Preset to be used is named _"My Preset 1"_, (Note: you'll need to change line 1 as necessary if a PDF Preset named _"My Preset 1"_ does not already exist). Currently it names the resultant PDF the same as the `.indd` document (minus the `.indd` suffix and adds a `.pdf` suffix). The resultant PDF is saved to your _Desktop_ folder

Comment: @RobC: As you say, OP should script InDesign directly. Might I suggest posting your code here as a complete answer.

Comment: Ok, i will try doing it in Indesign. Ultimately i want to make this a "quick action" with automator, so i can right-click the `.indd` file, select the quick action making it export to the same destination as the file i selected. keeping the same name but with the `.pdf` suffix is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would use InDesign's scripting API to make the PDF. If you study the entry for "export" in the AppleScript dictionary for InDesign. You'll learn the following command is possible:

```
export document 1 format PDF type to *SomeOutputPath* using PDF export preset "[Smallest File Size]"
```

If you really want to do this by clicking menus then take a look at InDesign's dictionary entry for "menu actions" and "invoke". These allow one to invoke a menu action:

```
set theAction to (menu actions whose name is "My Preset 1...")
invoke (item 1 of theAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

set thePdfPresetForInteractive to "Interactive"

export active document to file (export_path & "-interactive.pdf") format PDF type using PDF export preset thePdfPresetForInteractive without showing options